# AssertionFailedException while using TableColumnLayout in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I have a SWT Table inside a coposite, and i have used TableColumnLayout for dynamically resizing the table columns.

I get the following error while trying to launch the jface dialog which contains the table.

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: assertion failed: Unknown column layout data
```

This is the corresponding code used :

```
TableColumnLayout layout = new TableColumnLayout();
composite.setLayout(layout);

layout.setColumnData(column1, new ColumnWeightData(30));
layout.setColumnData(column2, new ColumnWeightData(30));
layout.setColumnData(column3, new ColumnWeightData(30));
layout.setColumnData(column4, new ColumnWeightData(30));
layout.setColumnData(column5, new ColumnWeightData(30));
```

Can anyone let me know What is causing me the error ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assertion is thrown if the column data is not an instance of `ColumnWeightData` or `ColumnPixelData` for all the defined columns. So my guess is that you have not set the column data for one of your columns.

Comment: to clarify: you MUST add:   tableColumnLayout.setColumnData( mycolumn, new ColumnWeightData( ... );. If you don't the above exception is thrown.